# Multinomial regression

Tags: spss, multinomial-distribution

When I run my multinomial regression (SPSS) I get errors that there are too many empty cells in the sub populations.  I have merged categories in my IVs to the extent possible.  My DV has 4 categories.  While less than ideal, could I run multiple models, each containing only a few IVs? Alternatively, I could take each category of my DV and merge the remaining three and conduct logistic regression on each category of my DV but using all my IVs.  For example, my 4 categories are occupations:  transportation, healthcare, education, and service.  Could I create a dichotomous variable transportation and non transportation (comprised of healthcare, education, and service) and run each as a binary logistic regression.  I'm not sure which option would be best?

Comment: I am not sure what "cells in subpopulations" exactly means. But, yes, you could reduce the number of IVs and you could do one-against-all classification. Did you try it and it removed the errors? Otherwise, you could consider imputation.

Comment: The exact error is as follows:  There are 389 (57.5%) cells (ie dependent variable levels by subpopulations) with zero frequencies.